# TShellListView Lazarus

Tags: lazarus, freepascal

Is it possible to set a item in a ShellListView to `visible=false`? I thought About something like `ShelLlistView.Items.visible(false)` but that does not exist and I have no idea for another solution so I hope someone can help me with this.

I can't post any Code for you yet because I don't have any ShellListView yet but I hope you can give me some advice how it could work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afaik, this is not possible because the `ListItem`s shown in the TShellListView have no `Visible` property.  However, according to Peter Below (TeamB), you can effectively "hide" an item by destroying it. See http://www.delphigroups.info/2/67/290279.html

Of course, if you wish to "unhide" an item hidden in this way, you would need to create & add a new node with the same `Caption`, etc.

This code works fine for me using the standard Lazarus TShellListView:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Item : TListItem;
begin
  Item := ShellListView1.Items[0];
  Caption := Item.Caption;
  Item.Free;
end;
```

and removes the first item in the list.

The following removes all the items in the `ShellListView`.  THe `downto` is to account for the fact that the `Count` value decreases on each iteration of the loop.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i : Integer;
begin
  for i := ShellListView1.Items.Count - 1 downto 0 do
    ShellListView1.Items[i].Free;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you i will try this soon. I said that I have no ShellListView created yet my Project because some People ask for Code but i don't have any Code for a shellListView because I will create it as soon as I Need it. I just wanted to know if it works and how I can do it. And the answer for that I got from you.

Comment: does this also work with a for loop to delete more than one item at the same time?

Comment: Well it should do, but you need to be careful when you write the code, because the number of items decreases by one each time around the loop.  But deleting Item[0] should always be ok as long as the list of items is not empty.

Comment: Alright deleteing the Item[0] works fine but as you already said deleteing more items is causing a error because I am decreasing the amount of items and increasing  the counter of the loop. But I Need to delete more items than only the first one. Do you have some advice how it should work. I'm trying to solve it but until now I haven't found any solution

Comment: Then you are doing something wrong, I'm agraid.  See the update to my answer that I've just posted.

Comment: Now it works I didn't even know that there exists something like `downto` Thank you very much